# D3.js for augmented browsing. Does it make sense?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the company where I am working, I receive data via an ASP web server on pages that contain rudimentary tables. I would like to augment my browsing experience of this data by adding sort and filtering capabilities to the tables and add bar graph or curves on the client side (via a browser add-on) as I do not have access to the server.

I can see D3.js examples get their data from Json, csv, or via api. Can I use functions like select to pump the data from the page itself and then insert into or remodel the page using D3? Does that make sense? I could not find much useful answers on searches where I put "D3.js" and "Augmented Browsing" together.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: You can put the data in a Javascript variable on the page and then use it with D3.